# orderby doesn't work in Laravel Eloquent advanced query

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'd like to sort my data by using orderby in Laravel Eloquent advanced query. Here is my code:

```
  $users = User::where(function($query){

       $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

  })->get()->toArray();
  var_dump($users);
```

But it doesn't work. Instead if I use orderby like this:

```
  $users = User::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
  var_dump($users);
```

It works.

Can anybody suggest how to make the orderby works for the advanced query? Thanks

Comment: When you have the `where` query inside a "function" like that, it is actually a *sub* query, so sorting the results doesn't affect the parent query. Well, actually that is just a guess, but it sounds right :P

Answer (score 2):

I tried all sorts of different combinations and found the orderBy must be outside the query function (or maybe should be the last one?). Here is the code which is working:

```
$users = User::where(function($query){

   // ......

})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: I've been having the same experience